# How can I stop a setInterval that starts onload and is within the body?

Tags: setinterval, onload, clearinterval

Apologies but I'm very new to coding. I hope this question is not too silly.
I thought I could use the clearInterval method, but it doesn't seem to work.

I would like to interrupt the rotate function with my stop button.
But I must be doing something wrong:

```
<body onload="rotate('target')">
    <h1 id="target">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwkyz</h1>
    <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

```
function rotate(id) {
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    let textNode = element.childNodes[0];
    let text = textNode.data;

    let int = setInterval(display, 500);
    function display() {
        text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
        textNode.data = text;
    };

    function stop() {
        clearInterval(int)
    };
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.